Norms for Subdomain Spaces and Decomposition in Sobolev Spaces
I am working on a problem involving domain decomposition in Sobolev spaces, and I need some guidance on the appropriate choice of norms for subdomain spaces.
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and let us decompose it into subdomains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, with $\bar{\Omega} = \bar{\Omega}_1 \cup \bar{\Omega}_2$ and $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2=\emptyset$.
Further, let us define $X_i = \{ u|_{\Omega_i} \mid u \in X \}$, where $X$ is a Sobolev space.

How should we choose the norm $\| \cdot \|_{X_i}$ for $X_i$?
and what is the correct way to relate the global norm to the local norms in this context? I mean, the global norm $\| \cdot \|_{X}$ for $\Omega$, should it satisfy an equality  like $\| \cdot \|_{X}^2 = \| \cdot \|_{X_1}^2 + \| \cdot \|_{X_2}^2$ or just an inequality when considering the decomposition?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, examples, or references to relevant literature that could help in understanding these aspects better.
Thank you very much in advance!

Will the global function $u$ be weakly differentiable across the boundaries of the subdomains or will they just be smooth on the interior of each subdomain?

The global function will be weakly differentiable across the boundaries of the subdomains.
